# How to read out a JSON returned object?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, jquery

I'm trying to code a notification system. An AJAX call runs a PHP script which selects every 'message' where 'new=1'. So I return the PHP array via JSON_encode back to the JS.

This returns the follow Object:
[image: JS object]

On my original page, you can see all 'sessions'. I want to 'update' the text of a div (which has new messages) with the numbers of new messages (= numbers of records in Object).

Now the problem comes: **I don't know how to read out that object.** Can someone please help me out?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the number of messages in *a specific session*, it would be something like this:

```
theObjectThatGotReturned[sessionName].length
// sessionName is the name of the session; in this case, "cgk" or "ur"
```

If you want the number of messages in *all sessions*, it would be something like this:

```
var newMessages = 0;
for(var i in theObjectThatGotReturned) {
   if ( /* here, you should test if i == a valid session name */) {
      newMessages += theObjectThatGotReturned[i].length;
   }
}
// newMessages is the number of new messages.
```

Comment: I want the number of messages of a specific session, but also for every sessions. So in this example it would be: returnedObj[cgk].length, and returnedObj[ur].length. The problem is that I don't know the "name" of the session (in this case UR & CGK) so I have to loop it.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean... If you don't know the name, how would you know when you've found the right session?

Comment: ...Now, if what you mean is that you won't know the name in advance, but you'll have it stored in a variable *at run-time*, then... You'd use my first code snippet. When you do `object[sessionName]`, the browser will take the value of `sessionName` and use that as the name of the property. So if, for example, `sessionName == "ur"`, then `object[sessionName] == object["ur"] == object.ur`.

Answer (score 0):

try: json = new Function("return ({"+ajax.responseText + "})");

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the OP already converted it from a string to an object. If I'm not mistaken, the image in their question is actually a screenshot of Safari's/Chrome's debugger showing the object's properties.